# Table goes out of container and behind navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, css-tables

I downloaded a template table from the internet and edited to how I wanted it, but for some reason it ignores the  assigned to it (I can't really explain it that well, you'll see it in the picture), but that is not the only problem; the dropdown navbar I have goes behind the table (and behind the image slider I have on the homepage) I've tried putting 'z-index=' (and various numbers) on every nav-class I have, this didn't work. I do have it so whenever someone scrolls the nav bar (and footer) stay where they are, maybe that has something to do with it, I don't know...

this is my html code:

```
<head>
<meta name="Copyright" content="Copyright XylCro Gaming 2015 - All Rights Reserved.">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Gear/PC Specs</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- don't forget! -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200)/*header hight*/ {
                    $('#nav').addClass('stuck');
                } else {
                    $('#nav').removeClass('stuck');
                }

            });
</script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container_wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="social_bar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="twitch" rel="external" href="http://www.twitch.tv/xylcro" target="_blank"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="youtube" rel="external" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSifAEUVDHNQ3mUFUGrUlGA" target="_blank"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="twitter" rel="external" href="https://twitter.com/xylcro" target="_blank"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="facebook" rel="external" href="https://www.facebook.com/XylCro" target="_blank"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
                    <!-- div socialbar and logo -->
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="nav_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="news.php">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">XylCro</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gear/PC Specs</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Archives</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Twitch Archive</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">YouTube Videos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Community</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- other divs -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="setup_wrapper">  
        <div class="setup scale">
            <span class="setup_title">Test Title</span>
                <ul class="features">
                    <li class="features_li">Test 1</li>
                    <li class="features_li">Test 2</li>
                    <li class="features_li">Test 3</li>
                    <li class="features_li">Test 4</li>
                    <li class="features_li">Test 5</li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy; XylCro Gaming 2015 - All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my css code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);
hr{
    display:block;
}
html{
    background-image:url(img/static/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:top center;
}
#container_wrapper{
    height:100%;    
}
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.4;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper{
    background-color:#F4F4F4;
    /*background-image:url(img/static/headertest.fw.png);
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%
}
#header{
    background-image:url(img/static/header.png);
    /*background-color: #F00;*/
    background-position:center;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 200px; /* need to change */
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;

}
#scoial_bar{
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
#social_bar ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:1;
}
#social_bar ul li{
    list-style:none outside none;
    padding:0;
    margin:6 0 0 15;
    display:inline-block;
}
#social_bar ul li a{
    height:50px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom;
    display:inline-block;
}
#social_bar ul li a.twitch{
    background-image:url(img/static/social/twitch_small.png);
    width:49px;
    margin:0 0; 
    text-indent:9999px;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
#social_bar li a.twitch:hover{
    background-image:url(img/static/social/twitch_small_hover.png);
}
#social_bar ul li a.youtube{
    background-image:url(img/static/social/youtube_small.png);
    width:72px;
    margin:0 0;
    text-indent:9999px;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
#social_bar li a.youtube:hover{
    background-image:url(img/static/social/youtube_small_hover.png);
}
#social_bar ul li a.twitter{
    background-image:url(img/static/social/twitter_small.png);
    width:63px;
    margin:0 0;
    text-indent:9999px;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
#social_bar li a.twitter:hover{
    background-image:url(img/static/social/twitter_small_hover.png);
}
#social_bar ul li a.facebook{
    background-image:url(img/static/social/facebook_small.png);
    width:28px;
    margin:0 0; 
    text-indent:9999px;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
#social_bar li a.facebook:hover{
    background-image:url(img/static/social/facebook_small_hover.png);
}
/* social and logo */
.stuck{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
#nav {
    background-color: #222;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
#nav_wrapper {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a: active {
    color: #F70;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    /*border: 5px solid #222;*/
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #699;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
#content{
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:1100px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:-20px auto;
    padding-top:3em;
    padding-bottom: 3em;

}
/* content and other divs */
#footer{
    color:#CCC;
    background-color: #222;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    height:50px;
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -3em;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    bottom:1;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 0 -4px 8px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.setup_wrapper {
    width:250px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.setup {
    width: 250px;
    background: #0F1012; 
    color: #f9f9f9;
    float: left;
}
.setup .setup_title {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;  
    background: #292b2e;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 17px 0 17px 0;
}
.features{
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999999;
}
.features_li{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.scale {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.8);
}
.scale .setup_title {
    color: #64AAA4;
}
```

the image with the problem: http://i1346.photobucket.com/albums/p683/dcf007/stupid%20site_zpsrtrctx3j.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding z-index requires that you also add positioning to the element.

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #222;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, please change position to fixed.  That should do the trick.